# Unity3D application always launches with same orientation on Android, regardless of OS orientation

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-orientation

When I launches app, it always has same orientation.

After some seconds, maybe in splash scene, it turns to OS orientation.

**I got that the orientation always 'Landscape Left' even if device was 'Landscape Right'.**

That is my problem.

I expect that app launches so that it matches the orientation of os.

Not portrait or landscape problem, but 'Landscape Left' or 'Landscape Right' problem ;(

PlayerSettings like as bellow.

http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/temp/48453-orientation.png

I set 'Auto Rotation' and checked 'Landscape Right' and 'Landscape Left'.

http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/temp/48455-minsdk.png

And I also set min SDK api level 14.

I set screenOrientation="landscape" in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="myMainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

Im using Unity3d 4.6.6p1

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to control the orientation in the device via Code [Screen.orientation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html).

You only need to ask wich are the current orientation and channge it to the other if you need it.

Hope It'll be helpfull to you.

Comment: Thanks, but it was already try solution.

At the first scene monobehaviour, I have put it in Awake() function. But still remains the problem. 

Launch after some seconds(2 or 3), app orientation got device orientation.

The only problem is occurred when the app start.